# Count documents since given timestamp

Tags: cloudant

I have documents with a timestamp property in milliseconds and a grouping property, emotion.

```
{
  emotion: "sad",
  timestamp: 1491889810157
}
```

I am trying to first filter the docs for timestamp > dynamic value, and then group and count based on the emotion property.

Map function:

```
function (doc) {
  if((Date.now()-doc.timestamp) <= 60000) {
    emit(doc.emotion, 1);
  }
}
```

Reduce:
_count

The ultimate result I'm looking for is (or similar with counts and the emotion value:

```
{
  "sad":8,
  "joy":15
}
```

The Node.js code that calls this view starts with:

```
db.view(design, view, {reduce: true, group: true, update: true}, (err, body) => {
```

However, the Map Reduce function returns older docs that don't meet the if condition. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is explained in the [CouchDB views documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html) (emphasis is mine):

> When you query your view, CouchDB takes the source code and runs it for you on every document in the database. If you have a lot of documents, that takes quite a bit of time and you might wonder if it is not horribly inefficient to do this. Yes, it would be, but CouchDB is designed to avoid any extra costs: *it only runs through all documents once, when you first query your view. If a document is changed, the map function is only run once, to recompute the keys and values for that single document.*

Assuming that your documents haven't changed the condition is not re-evaluated when you query the view and documents with older timestamps are returned.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The documents match the view at the time they are added/edited, but if the documents don't change, then the view doesn't update and so the old documents stay in the results.